# How to have a Image Toolbar?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, crop

Actually I wish to do the Image Crop or Resize, etc with my picture from the program,
For that I think I need a image toolbar for my project...If its correct kindly give me some ideas to learn the task...

Comment: Could you be more specific? What I understand: you need a crop library. Right?

Comment: Image controls like Crop,Resize, with editing the Images, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is basically done using javascript and/or flash.

When submitting to server you'll retrieve the coordinates of your selection to allow an image processing to be done (cropping/resizing).

Take a look at [jCrop](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php)